# How can I select distinct dates from a database, when it's formatted as DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, date

I have a database setup similarly to this

The output of

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(mytable);
```

is

```
0|id|INTEGER
1|mydatetime|text
```

And it looks like this

```
|__id__|_____mydatetime_____|
|   0  | 2016-10-11 12:10:22|
|   1  | 2016-10-11 12:11:22|
|   2  | 2016-10-12 10:45:45|
|   3  | 2016-10-12 11:12:12|
```

In Ruby on Rails, I'd like to select all of the rows with the same date (ignoring time). And I'm looping through them, to do something for every date.  For example:

If I had the same database, and instead of `DateTime` it was formatted as just the `Date` I would do something similar to below:

```
distinctDate = MyTable.select(:mydatetime).distinct.to_a

distinctDate.each do |x|
    put x
end
```

But how can I write the select with the distinct, and it also ignore the time?

Comment: Just select a computed property that is the substring you're interested in? [`substr`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) is what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MyTable.pluck("distinct date(updated_at)")
```

That will give you back an array of distinct dates, then you can process them however you need to in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use sqlite's [date()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function to get only the date part of DateTime field.
In your example:

```
distinctDate = MyTable.select('date(mydatetime)').distinct.to_a
```

And if you need only array of column values instead of rows, you can use ActiveRecord's [pluck()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) method:

```
distinctDate = MyTable.distinct.pluck('date(mydatetime)')
```